# wsdl date type transformed to XMLGregorianCalendar when generate client soap

Tags: java, cxf, wsimport

I can't understand why my field `dateTransaction`

changed from `date` type to `XMLGregorianCalendar` after generating the soap client ( with wsimpot or cxf maven plugin)

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.xxxxxx.xxr/xx/wsdl/service/objets/v1" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns="http://www.xxxxxx.xxr/xx/wsdl/service/objets/v1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="RequeteService" type="RequeteService"/>

            <xs:element name="dateTransaction" type="xs:date" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>

    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

here is my generated class :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "RequeteService", propOrder = {

    "dateTransaction",
    ....
})
    public class RequeteService{

      .....
        @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
        protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateTransaction;
```

here is my plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <useJdkToolchainExecutable>false</useJdkToolchainExecutable>
                    <wsdlDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                    <packageName>xxxx.xxxx.ws.api</packageName>
                    <keep>true</keep>
                    <sourceDestDir>${project.basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the JDK's (and XSD) standard handling for Xml 'date' types. XMLGregorianCalendar handles all the XML and timezone specifics. If you want to map the xml date (or dateTime) attributes to a different Java date(time) object, you can do that using a binding file to map the file to something else using an Adapter.

Here is a DZone article about it: 
[Customizing XML date(time) field generation w/ XJB](https://dzone.com/articles/jaxb-customization-xsddatetime)